# fluid CSS framework

Tags: responsive-design, css-frameworks

I've googled all day looking for a light weight grid framework, but expecting something fluid and responsive -- perhaps my requirements are in conflict with each other.

I have looked at inuit.css and bootstrap and everything in between.

Ideally I find something low-level like reset.css and a simple grid system and just build from there.

This is for the admin panel of a backend of a web site so the 960 grid is not really what I want. Ideally the app should consume all the available space with media queries hiding portions which are less relevant when screen real estate is at a premium.

Is there such a thing? Seems every framework I looked at centered everything and when I maximized my window content just centered.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a framework that met your needs...I'm in the same boat...

Answer (score 1):

My framework, [Jeet 3](http://jeetframework.com), will do that with ease.

```
header
    background blue
.left_sidebar
    col(1/4)
.main
    col(3/4)
```

..would create a header at the top with a blue bg, a 1/4 left sidebar that was flush against the left side, and a main container next to that sidebar (separated by a fluid gutter) that took up 3/4 (the rest).

If you wanted to add a logo that matched up with the width of your sidebar, and some nav that was 1/4 away from your logo, then...

```
header
    background blue
    .logo
        col(1/4)
    nav
        col(2/4, offset: -1/4)
        a
            col(1/4)
.left_sidebar
    col(1/4)
.main
    col(3/4)
```

Don't want gutters? Use `span()` instead.

- IE8+ with decent IE7 degradation
- Accepts any fraction and/or decimal
- Gutters are consistent as you nest so long as you pass parent ratio context (check the demo screencast)
- Jeet is mostly a grid system, but tag teams with Axis CSS which is like a beautiful UI library
- Built on Stylus which is easily the sexiest preprocessor. It's flexible so you can use a plethora of syntax and it will work.

https://github.com/CorySimmons/jeet/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Foundation 4](http://foundation.zurb.com/download.php)? You can customize the framework and only download the grid framework.

Comment: I've looked into it yes...but its still quite large (like bootstrap) is it not? Does it support fluidity?

Comment: It's large if you download the whole package. What I recommend is just to download the CSS for the grid system. Customize download > check Grid only. It's about 7K, which is relatively small in my opinion.<br/>And it's fluid grid.

Comment: I have long since settled on yahoo pure...its very compact and makes few asdumptions...

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of shameless self-promotion I'll throw mine into the ring:
[Loxley](https://bitbucket.org/drewrobey/loxley.css).

It's essentially a single CSS file containing a set of media queries and grid system.